# How to unmask the variable _ in python once it is masked with local variable in python interpreter

Tags: python, variables, interpreter

I am starting python and doing some calculations in the python interpreter, calculation results are stored in read only built-in variable `_`. However when I  declared a variable with name `_` , the earlier one is masked. Now results are not stored in `_` . How do I un-mask it. See the example I gave

*before down voting, try to understand the question*

```
>>> 3+5
8
>>> _
8
>>>_ = 3
>>> 4*3
12
>>>4+4
8
>>> _
3
```

from this time, calculation results are not stored in `_`
The question is how to get evaluated results to be stored in `_` from this afterwards

Thank you @Matthias, you answered my question to use `del`

```
>>> del _
```

Comment: Why would you use `_` anyway? Per the convention, `_` is used when unpacking a value you are not interested in, for example, `value_you_want, _ = function_that_returns_a_2_tuple()`

Comment: @DeepSpace i was experimenting, and want to unmask it

Comment: If you are talking about the REPL, it is not clear what you mean by "unmasking". In the REPL `_` is just a shorthand to the last evaluated value

Comment: @DeepSpace to get the calculation results to be stored in `_` again

Comment: You don't have to do anything. The last evaluated value is automatically stored in `_`

Comment: @DeepSpace NO it is not stored, you can check it

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] where you can prove that it does not

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are explicitly doing `_ = 1` then `_` will not be updated automatically, which returns me to the first comment: you should not use `_` as it is a convention for a value you don't care about. You clearly care about this value, so don't use `_`

Comment: @DeepSpace i got your point, the question is how to get it back

Comment: @The Scientific Method: Why you need to assign `_` instead of using any other variable name ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer i know what you are saying,  answer the question

Comment: @TheScientificMethod BTW are you sure it's an actual example? If your interpreter returns `7` for `3+5` then we have an entire different problem to solve here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the REPL `_` is a shorthand that will automatically store the last evaluated value, unless you explicitly assign to it.

The solutions are:

- (**Good**) Don't explicitly assign to it to begin with. It is going against the convention of using `_` for values that you don't care about but have to be assigned, for example:

  ```
  value_you_want, _ = function_that_returns_a_2_tuple()
  ```

  Use a good and meaningful variable name
- (**Bad**) You can use `del _` to get rid of the `_` that you explicitly created, then it will automatically get the last evaluated value again.

  ```
  >>> 1 + 1
  2
  >>> _
  2
  >>> _ = 1
  >>> _
  1
  >>> 2 + 2
  4
  >>> _
  1
  >>> del _
  >>> 2 + 2
  4
  >>> _
  4
  ```

Comment: Thanks but you did not answer my question, my question is how to get it back

Comment: @The Scientific Method, what do you want to get back ?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod You asked `The question is how to get evaluated results to be stored in _ from this afterwards` My answer fully answers this question

Comment: @actulaly Matthias  answered my question to use `del`, thank you for your efforts

Comment: @TheScientificMethod Did you read the **whole** answer? it also mentions `del`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the same variable for more than one thing. If you re-declare it, you will lose the previous value. Instead of using `_` twice, use two different variable names.

Comment: it is built-in variable, the question is how do i unmask it?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod What do you mean by "unmasking"? In the REPL `_` is just a shorthand to the last evaluated value

Comment: @DeepSpace that property  now masked, due to declared the question is how to get it back

Comment: Explicit: `_` is **not** a built-in variable. Maybe you just want `del _`.

Comment: @Matthias ok, how to get it back its property is the question

Comment: As I said: `del _`. Worked for me. Or restart your IDE.

Comment: @Matthias THank you , you answered my question to use `del`